# Simple messaging app with users specifying own keys

Tags: encryption, decryption

If I made a simple messaging app which is encrypting messages with some algorithm with a key the user types in the application, and which then sends the encrypted message to another user without storing anything anywhere, and when the recipient user will get the encrypted message he similarly will type in the key in order to encrypt the message. Is there any way to spy on this messages except to break the key itself?

Comment: There might be  a lot of problems, like insecure encryption algorithm, bug in the application which can be used as backdoor ... . Let's say one can write an application which does what you want in a secure way but one can also mess it up. Also, you did not address the problem of how the user gets the secret shared key in a secure way in the first place.

Comment: Users can get secret keys only OUT of application. For example if you and i want to communicate wich eachother, we would need first to meet in order to establish our key, or we would exchange key on some other way. It would not be automatic end-to-end encryption with key time for only one message like whats'app, facebook and telegram use, it would be platform for secret chating between people which knows eachother and want to establish secure messaging.

Answer (score 2):

The security of your encryption scheme relies basically on 2 factors.

1. Security of the devices the app runs on. If the devices are compromised and the attacker can spy on the on-screen keyboard then it is game over because the key is compromised
2. The secure key exchange to the recipient of the message. In order for it to be considered secure, you need to use a completely different channel to agree on the key. Verbal communication (over which medium? Not the same device!), another device (a PC, maybe?), classical mail?